# ng-prime datatable have 2 columns as datakey?

Tags: angular, primeng

Is there anyway to combine 2 columns as the `datakey` on data table?

For instance, I need `col1` and `col2` to be the key so I can expand the row based on that key.

I've tried

```
dataKey="col1, col2"
```

and

```
dataKey="col1" dataKey="col2"
```

Comment: You can create a new key which is the concatenation of `col1` and `col2`.

Answer (score 2):

PrimeNG does not support dataKey to have multiple values. As [@Antikhippe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4359365/antikhippe) mentioned in the comment, you can have a new column, e.g. "key1-key2", which has the combination of the needed columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this by passing a function, defined in the corresponding `component.ts` file as the value of dataKey. The function will take one argument, which will be an object corresponding to a single row of the table.

In html:

```html
dataKey="getDataKey"
```

In component.ts

```js
getDataKey(event) {
  return event.col1 + event.col2;
}
```

Credit to https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/5383#issuecomment-728713523 for the solution

Comment: Tried it on primeng 16 and it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm on primeng 14.2.3 - maybe you need a different solution for primeng16